# Spark scala GroupByCount operation using scala futures

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections, concurrent.futures

I have a dataFrame with 50 columns and I wanted to do groupBycount on 10 columns in parallel mode.

```
        val parallelism = Columns.length
        val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(parallelism)
        val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(executor)
        val tasks: Seq[String] = groupByOneCountColumns
        val results = tasks.map(query => {
          Future{
            //spark stuff here
            val groupByCount: Array[ResponseOnGroupByCount] = srcDF
              .groupBy(query)
              .count()
              .map(x => ResponseOnGroupByCount(query.toString, x.getString(0), x.getLong(1)))(encoder)
              .collect()
            result += Json.toJson(groupByCount)
          }(ec)
        })
        val allDone = Future.sequence(results)
        //wait for results
        Await.result(allDone, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf)
        executor.shutdown //otherwise jvm will probably not exit
```

Throws

```
Task not serializable
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable


Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl
```

I have tried using .par operation to parallelize it is throwing some other issue.I think this one will help us.

Thanks in Advance.